# How can I eliminate the arc of the line at the vertex in the Qt line graph?

Tags: c++, qt5, c++14

```cpp
...

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class Chart : public QChart {
private:
    QSplineSeries *splineSeries;
    QTimer *timer;
    QValueAxis *m_axisX;
    QValueAxis *m_axisY;
    double x{};
    double y{};
    bool just{true};
public:
    explicit Chart(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags = {});
};

Chart::Chart(QGraphicsItem *parent, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags) :
        QChart(QChart::ChartTypeCartesian, parent, wFlags) {
    this->splineSeries = new QSplineSeries();
    this->m_axisX = new QValueAxis;
    this->m_axisY = new QValueAxis;

    this->setAnimationEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);
    this->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);

    QPen pen(QColorConstants::DarkGreen);
    pen.setWidth(2);
    this->splineSeries->setPen(pen);

    ...
}
```

[image]

In the line chart, the line around each point has some curvature, which is a little uncomfortable for such a curve. How can I cancel it?

Comment: use QLineSeries instead of QSplineSeries

Comment: @eyllanesc `QLineSeries` does not have an arc, but no new points are added, and the stretch animation of the polyline, `this->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations)` becomes an invalid setting.